# finding all jpgs with name date size and directory

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, cmd.exe

**Windows 10 or XP**

I need to find all jpg files in an external hard drive: they are in different directories.

That output would be added to an ascii file alljpg.txt

```
Name date size directory 
dsc002245.jpg  11/12/2022  xxbytes  e:/park/something/
```

I have several cameras that apply the same prefix and lots of files with the same names. I want to create a master list of all jpgs on all hard drives to find them.

Depending what I have plugged in the computer will give drives a different letter.

I have renamed each drive so when that particular drive is being gleaned.

This:

```
dsc002245.jpg  11/12/2022  xxbytes  e:/park/something/
```

will become this:

```
dsc002245.jpg  11/12/2022  xxbytes  e:/park/something/ DR04
```

with 04 being the name I gave to that drive.

Is there a command line order that will do this?

```
Name date size directory 
dsc002245.jpg  11/12/2022  xxbytes  e:/park/something/
```

the complete list of jpgs with date size directory, sent to a text file.

Comment: I tried to format the question sensibly; if I changed the intended meaning please [edit] corrections in.

Comment: Your next task will be to find where your camera's naming convention is stored & change it to not re-use numbers. Then all you need to do is wait until it almost reaches 9,999 & change the letters to DSD, then round you go again for another 10k… DSE & onward...

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I started with win 10 to find all jpg files
search .. *.jpg size:medium
On the first one I clicked ctrl
hold shift and right click
copy as path
... lets me copy the whole list and paste it into a text file

It will generate strings like this
"C:\MyStuff\Buttons\!-ourturf2.jpg"
but not the info

Now I knew the names of all the folders the jpgs were found in
using gwbasic I created a batch file 
which changed to each directory dir

Answer (score 0):

To create a file with filenames; Try this brute force thing:

`C:\> dir /s /b | find /i ".jpg > allJPG.txt`

Now, that is what MS-DOS can handle, to get date and size of the files you need some kind of utility do extract that for you.

If you cannot find such a thingie compiled for DOS, then try installing e.g. cygwin or similar, then learn to use Linux `find`, which is more capable.

Windows 10 on the other hand has more options...
*leaving that for others...*

NOTE:
https://exiftool.org/
will rename your files, based on EXIF data. e.g. pick out "Date taken", reformat that text and use it in a rename.